# Why does PHP not have a mysqli.default_database runtime setting?

Tags: php, mysqli, runtime, directive

Well not much to explain here, the title asks the question. I added a bit of background information below to explain what I'm trying to achieve and how this question came up.

#### Background

I'm working on some PHP applications.  I'm trying to set up the Apache pull method as described here: https://www.codementor.io/@ccornutt/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-kvcbrk55z to remove the hardcoded credentials from the application. The company I work for does not want us hard-coding DB credentials (anymore), and  my boss wants me to use the ini vars.

During the process, I had to get a sysadmin to change the Apache config to set those variables on the stage and in production, when he set those he asked

> why is there no runtime setting for a default database name?

I honestly didn't have an answer, so for the DB name I decided to use the value of `getenv()` then we named the environment `mysqli.default_database` and gave it a value of the DB name.

Now I have the same question but there doesn't seem to be any answer out there?

I feel like using the environment is probably not the right way, but it seems like no one around my work does it the same way.  Other guys appear to use a config file that's different for each server, some guys use the ini vars... and these old applications I'm working on are all hard-coded.

Can anyone explain why that setting doesn't exist?  Or am I just misunderstanding?

Comment: Do you mean [PHP's mysqli runtime configuration settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php)? They're not Apache-related.

Comment: @Jeto Yes those ones, sorry I have fixed the question I have Apache on my mind - I'm very new to development and I do not fully understand how servers and ini settings work.  I've mostly done front-end work so I'm probably using the wrong terminology.  Why this company has me doing this i'll never know... still trying to learn.